# Generate custom item control from Dependency Property as Item Source in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm making a UserControl to generate a list of attached files from Dependency Property as ItemSource. But the ItemSource (DependencyProperty) count is 0.
I tried debugging and realized that the ObservableCollection in ViewModel was bound after the Constructor of my UserControl is initialized.

I'm coding in MVVM pattern, I made a function to prepare some sample data for ObservableCollection in ViewModel and inside the MainWindow I bound the DataContext of my UserControl with that ViewModel then set the ItemSource for ObservableCollection

My ViewModel code-behind:

```
//The properties
  ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel> filesAttachment;
        public ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel> FilesAttachment
        {
            get { return filesAttachment; }
            set { filesAttachment = value; OnPropertyChanged("FilesAttachment"); }
        }
//The function prepare sample data
 private ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel> PrepareData()
        {
            FilesAttachment.Add(new FileAttachmentModel() { FileName = "TrackA", FilePath = "D:\trackA.png" });
            FilesAttachment.Add(new FileAttachmentModel() { FileName = "TrackB", FilePath = "D:\trackB.png" });
            FilesAttachment.Add(new FileAttachmentModel() { FileName = "TrackC", FilePath = "D:\trackC.png" });

        }
```

My UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MailSender.Controls.FileAttachment.FileAttachment"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MailSender.Controls.FileAttachment"            
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             Name="fileAttachmentUC"
             >
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=fileAttachmentUC,Path=DataContext,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="wrapPanel">

        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My UserControl code-behind:

```
//the property ItemSource
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel>), typeof(FileAttachment),new UIPropertyMetadata());

//the wrapper property
 public ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel> ItemSource
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);

            }
        }

//the function to generate each file attachment and add them to the Wrappanel in UserControl
//I call this function inside constructor of UserControl and pass ItemSource as parameter 
 void GenerateFileItem(ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel> lstFileAttachment)
        {
            if (lstFileAttachment != null && lstFileAttachment.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (var item in lstFileAttachment)
                {
                    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
                    TextBlock tbFileName = new TextBlock() { Text = item.FileName };
                    Button btFilePath = new Button() { Content = "X", Tag = item.FilePath };
                    btFilePath.Click += BtFilePath_Click;
                    sp.Children.Add(tbFileName);
                    sp.Children.Add(btFilePath);
                    sp.Style = Application.Current.FindResource("stackFileItem") as Style;
                    wrapPanel.Children.Add(sp);
                }
            }

        }
```

In Usage:

```
<control:FileAttachment DataContext="{StaticResource vmMainWindow}" ItemSource="{Binding FilesAttachment,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

What I expect is to make a container for attached files like Outlook of Microsoft. Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use an ItemsControl with the WrapPanel in its ItemsPanel and the StackPanel in its ItemTemplate?

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply, because I got disconnected whole lastnight. I searched some forum about WPF and they used the ItemControl but I had just learnt WPF about 1 month so I was still confused with it. I appreciate if you can give me more advise with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `GenerateFileItem` whenever the dependency property is set using a `PropertyChangedCallback`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel>), typeof(FileAttachment), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnChanged));

//the wrapper property
public ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel> ItemSource
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<FileAttachmentModel>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FileAttachment fa = (FileAttachment)d;
    fa.GenerateFileItem(fa.ItemSource);
}
```

The `ItemSource` property cannot be set before the `UserControl` has been initialized.

Comment: I'm so sorry for late reply because I was disconnected lastnight. Your solution made my day. It's work perfectly. I have just been with WPF 1 month so I still need to learn more. :D. I marked the answer in case someone else face the thing like me.

Comment: @binhnguyen Please note that this is only half of the solution. In order to make it fully functional (and to make sense of using an ObservableCollection) you would also have to attach a CollectionChanged event handler to the ItemSource value in the OnChanged method. If you don't do it (as shown in this answer) you wouldn't even need to use an ObservableCollection at all. IMO you have accepted the answer too early.

Comment: I got it, I created new DependencyProperty to check the PropertyChanged and re-call the GenerateFileItem function to add new FileAttachment item control to UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

What I was facing is the ObservableCollection I generate in ViewModel is initialized after the UserControl is initialized. The @mm8 solution has fixed my problem by waiting for the ObservableCollection in ViewModel is initialized first and then pass it by the property I bound in MainWindow. Then the UserControl will be initialized and get the ObservableCollection that is passed from ViewModel then generate the custom controls inside my "wrapPanel".

Comment: Please note that you don't need to write an explanation why you accepted an answer.